# Convert QFont styleName to stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

everyone. Please, help me.

Imagine, I have a widget form and display values on it, and I want the values' labels to be displayed with some other font than the other text labels. So I give them a css class name for example "Value" and want to set some font through the stylesheet (QLabel.Value {...}).
I try to set up **QLabel**'s font through the **Qt Designers** *stylesheet dialog*, but if I select for example font **Lato** with style **Medium**, **Designer** converts it to string:

```
font: 57 12pt "Lato";
```

and the label shows very thin font which is absolutely not the **Medium** style.

If I try another font **Gotham** with style **Book**, the **Designer** doesn't see the stylename at all and outputs:

```
  font: 12pt "Gotham".
```

So the questions are:

1. Do stylesheets support font style names?
2. If no, which qt way I can assign required font to all of the labels (or widgets) of the same type?

P.S. I'm using Windows 10, Qt 15.2 MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using style sheets for settings custom fonts on widgets:

1. They are error-prone.
2. Qt doesn't have any validator for it.

You could easily use `QFont` and `QLabel::setFont` (or whatever widget you use for displaying your information). For example with this:

```cpp
auto font_1()
{
        QFont f;
        f.setFamily("Monospace");
        f.setWeight(10);
        f.setBold(true);
        return f;
}

void change_fonts(std::vector<QLabel*> const& lbns)
{
        for (auto const& lbn : lbns) {
                lbn->setFont(font_1());
        }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        auto const win = new QDialog;
        auto const lbn1 = new QLabel("Ghasem Ramezani");
        auto const lbn2 = new QLabel("Ghasem Ramezani");
        auto const lay = new QVBoxLayout;
        change_fonts({lbn1, lbn2});
        lay->addWidget(lbn1);
        lay->addWidget(lbn2);
        win->setLayout(lay);
        win->show();
        return app.exec();
}
```

You could change the labels font:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Of course, you are right, but stylesheets let do it automatically. It is enough to mark needed labels with class Title, and some others with class Values, and they get different fonts. But may be, you are right, the only way to manually setFont for each widget not a big problem.

Comment: @AlexNevskiy, You are welcome. Using style sheets is more error-prone than manually setting font over each widget. Qt doesn't even have a validator for style sheets. But with `QFont` you get a compile-time error if you do anything wrong.